# How do you say "cookies", in the sense of website cookies?

Tags: translation, word, websites

How do you say "Cookies" in Chinese?

I mean website cookies.

I often see "cookies" or 曲奇 but I would like to know which terms is mostly used.

Comment: iciba：

N-COUNT “甜饼”，网络跟踪器(记录上网用户信息的软件) A cookie is a piece of computer software which enables a website you have visited to recognize you if you visit it again.
https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%94%9C%E9%A5%BC

Comment: Some of my friends have web dev experience. We usually just say "cookie" in English. Like "这个网站用cookie"

Comment: Many computer related terms are not translated. Ping, DNS, cookies ...

Comment: You can open your browser, set its language to Chinese, and find out they just use the English word "cookie" in Settings.

Comment: Thanks for all your feedback. That's what I thought of but wondered if you used more of a Chinese equivalent. Apparently not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An explanation that "cookie"/"cookies" (the English words) are used in Chinese has already been given.  But to give an idea of where and how this phrase is used:

1. It's staightforward to Baidu search for [`浏览器cookies`](https://www.baidu.com/s?wd=%E6%B5%8F%E8%A7%88%E5%99%A8cookies) = "browser cookies" and come up with many examples of this phrase being used in the context of browsers.
2. It can be found used in company privacy policies:

   > 我们会在您的计算机或移动设备上发送一个或多个名为Cookies的小数据文件，指定给您的Cookies 是唯一的，它只能被将Cookies发布给您的域中的Web服务器读取。
   >   <sub>[Jingdong privacy policy](https://about.jd.com/privacy/)</sub>
   >
   > 为确保网站正常运转，我们有时会在计算机或移动设备上存储名为 Cookie 的小数据文件。
   >   <sub>[Huawei privacy policy](https://www.huawei.com/cn/privacy-policy)</sub>
   >
   > 为确保网站正常高效运转、为您获得更轻松的访问体验、向您推荐您可能感兴趣的内容，我们会在您的设备终端\系统上存储名为 Cookie的小数据文件。
   >   <sub>[Meituan privacy policy](https://www.meituan.com/about/privacy/#scs2)</sub>
3. You can see the word "cookie" used in screenshots such as

   > [image]
   >
   > <sub>Jingdong help center [帮助中心](https://www.jd.com/phb/zhishi/575f782eca458d1d.html)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

We also say "Cookie(s)" actually, because in Chinese "Cookies" is "存储在用户本地终端上的数据" which is an explanation rather than a word, and it's too long.